# Spring web and security. Add /api prefix to login route

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using spring security. I need to add the /api prefix to the login route. I am extending the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` class

JWTAuthenticationFiler.class

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends 
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter{
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
        User creds = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(request.getInputStream(), User.class);

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        creds.getUsername(),
                        creds.getPassword(),
                        new ArrayList<>())
        );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, 
                                        HttpServletResponse response, 
                                        FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String token = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + SecurityConstants.EXPIRATION_TIME))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SecurityConstants.SECRET.getBytes())
            .compact();
    response.addHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING, token);
}

}
```

The base class contains in constructor instantiation of the login route:

```
public class UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends
    AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
// ~ Static fields/initializers
// =====================================================================================

public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY = "username";
public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY = "password";

private String usernameParameter = SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY;
private String passwordParameter = SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY;
private boolean postOnly = true;

// ~ Constructors
// ===================================================================================================

public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter() {
    super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
}

...
```

I have to override somehow the "/login" to "/api/login". How to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the default value for `filterProcessesUrl` in your custom authentication filter extending [`UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html) you have to use [`setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html#setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher-org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher-), see [`AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html):

> This filter will intercept a request and attempt to perform authentication from that request if the request matches the `setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(RequestMatcher)`.

with a `RequestMatcher` that matches your custom URL.

You can call the setter in your constructor, in your factory method or in XML configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you use the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. Therefore you have to use the formLogin in order to set the login endpoint.

```
public class SecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http.authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/apilogin*").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and().formLogin().loginPage("/apilogin")
      .and().httpBasic();
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer but my question was formulated bad. Can you check the question once again please?

Comment: You don't need `.antMatchers("/apilogin*").permitAll()`. Moreover the matching can be too broad.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to call setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher on the filter when defining the bean in your configuration class.

```
code.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(
    new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/login","POST"));

@Bean
public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter authFilter = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter();
    authFilter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login","POST"));

    return authFilter;
}
```